# How to save objects traced using image trace into vector components?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

So, I have a jpg logo which I traced using image trace in Illustrator and it traced successfully with the light blue (cyan) lines around it.

How do I convert this into a vector component which I can then move onto a transparent background?

[image]

Comment: The light blue would indicate they are guides. Did You turn the results into guides? Don't do that. Just click the `Expand` button in the Control Bar across the top of the screen.

Comment: Could you please send a screenshot to describe this?

Comment: I see white shapes on a grey background. Is the grey background a part of your JPG or is it the artboard? What is the used Illustrator version? Have you painted the cyan lines manually or did the automatic Live Trace create them?

Comment: The grey background is part of the jpg. I want to remove that part and set the other elements onto a new artboard.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you have a while tried the options in the tracing options dialog. I guess you have found these:

[image]

Preview shows your original image and the outlines of the result (=cyan)

The essentials (Expand, Ungroup, kill the JPG and use your vectors) is already said in another answer. My texts hopefully add to it "How".

At first click the Trace button to execute the previewed tracing surely. After it the dialog is unnecessary.

You must expand the trace. That means "Make it final, no more adjustable with tracing options". Goto Object > Live Trace > Expand.

Get a habit to keep the appearance panel visible. It shows allways something essential of the selected object. Now it shows that there's an unexpanded Trace:

[image]

Expanding generates usually a group, if the image or tracing settings were complex as yours. Select the tracing result and goto Object > Ungroup. Repeat the selecting an ungrouping until there's nothing ungroupable left. Here is the view before ungrouping:

[image]

NOTE: Ungrouping is not allways enough. There can in complex objects be also clipping masks which should be released (Object > Clipping Mask > Release) before the parts can be separated. That's not the case now.

After ungrouping you can have several shapes. In my example there's

- a black rectangle with a hole (= a compound path, it holds a copy of the white shape and a black solid rectangle)
- outline of the whole image
- the white shape, which in your case probably is the wanted one

NOTE: in tracing options it's possible to ignore white areas. It wasn't selected now.

I placed a green background and moved the parts apart to make them visible:

[image]

The job would have been a little more simpler if you had inverted your JPG to make the interesting part darkest. In that case BW tracing would generate only one black shape.

Answer (score 0):

Image trace - expand - ungroup.
Select the .jpeg, delete it and do with vectors as you please.